# Setting layouts to the size of their contents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have a simple XML I am trying to inflate, and struggling with the layout.  What I want to achieve is quite simple (or so I thought), so I am sure I am going about it incorrectly.  Basically I have three elements,  2 TextViews, and an Imageview.   I want the two text boxes placed on top of one another, with the image on the right of them, aligned to the right side, and its view fitted it the size of the image.  Like this:

```
    Text 1                     |==| 
Text 2 would be below text 1   |==|
```

Heres my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/entry_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/entry1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tab_host_default_height"
            android:text="@string/test_string"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/entry2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/test_string" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/entry3"
            style="@style/ImageButtonBDTheme"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/activated_background_holo_light"
            android:contentDescription="@string/click_for_repair_report"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/entry_link" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is that I cannot get the image to display without hard coding the size of the LinearLayout containing the two text boxes.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/entry_container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
              android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/entry1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tab_host_default_height"
                android:text="@string/test_string"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/entry2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:text="@string/test_string" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/entry3"
                style="@style/ImageButtonBDTheme"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/activated_background_holo_light"
                android:contentDescription="@string/click_for_repair_report"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/entry_link" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You got it! Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Could you possibly explain how this works?  I would have thought setting a weight in one, but not the other would only display that element.

Comment: what ever size is required to show imagebutton it will take  and rest of size is used by textview layout..

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/entry_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="0dp"                  //changes here
         android:layout_weight="0.6"                 //changes here
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/entry1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tab_host_default_height"
            android:text="@string/test_string"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/entry2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/test_string" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"              //changes here
        android:layout_weight="0.4"                //changes here
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/entry3"
            style="@style/ImageButtonBDTheme"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/activated_background_holo_light"
            android:contentDescription="@string/click_for_repair_report"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/entry_link" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but setting the weight does not fit it to the size of the image.  I'm trying to make the layout containing the view the exact size of the image+padding, with the LinearLayout containing the text using the rest

Comment: @xceph then give image layout width as wrap_content and that text layout weight as 1

Answer (score 1):

Always Use Relative Layout, it requires lesser no. of code as compared to other Layouts.

Try below, i guess this is what you want, set Padding/Margin according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/entry_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entry1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tab_host_default_height"
        android:text="@string/test_string"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entry2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/entry1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/test_string" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/entry3"
        style="@style/ImageButtonBDTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/click_for_repair_report"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/entry_link" />

</RelativeLayout>
```